# How can i get the sum of a MySQL table's field for today date?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am building a simple shopping cart using PHP and as per title i want to get the sum (total earnings) of `price` field of `orders` table but only for today date.

I created the following function but i can get the total earnings for the last day there were earnings, not today. For example if Today is Friday and the last day which there were earnings are Monday($180), then the result i get is Monday:$180 instead of Friday:$0 which is what i want.

Here is what i have now:

```
    public function getTotalEarningsToday()
    {
        $records = (new Query())->select([
                'sum(price) as count',
                "from_unixtime(updated_at, '%Y-%m-%d') as day",
                 ])
            ->from(Orders::tableName())
            ->orderBy('day desc')
            ->groupBy('day')
            ->indexBy('day')
            ->limit(1)
            ->where(['status' => Orders::STATUS_COMPLETED])
            ->all();

        return $records;
    }
```

I tried to store the current date in a variable and do something like that:

```
   public function getTotalEarningsToday()
    {
        $todayDate = date("d.m.Y H:i");
        $records = (new Query())->select([
                'sum(price) as count',
                "from_unixtime(updated_at, '$todayDate') as day",
                 ])
            ->from(Orders::tableName())
            ->orderBy('day desc')
            ->groupBy('day')
            ->indexBy('day')
            ->limit(1)
            ->where(['status' => Orders::STATUS_COMPLETED])
            ->all();

        return $records;
    }
```

and now i get the today date inside the Array but still i can't get the right sum earnings records:

```
Array ( [count] => 61.35 [day] => 21.02.2022 09:18 ) )
```

It should be:

```
  Array ( [count] => 0 [day] => 21.02.2022 09:18 ) )
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: you are summing up the price while you should count id in the specific table  ``` $records = (new Query())->select([
                'count(id) as count',
                "from_unixtime(updated_at, '$todayDate') as day",
                 ])```

Comment: Isnt it right? Because there are days that may have multiple orders/earnings, so i have to get the total amount of earnings for the day

Comment: your sql query should look like this `SELECT * FROM table WHERE updated_at >= '2022-02-21 00:00' AND updated_at <= '2022-02-21 23:59'`. I'm not familiar with the framework you mentioned so change it to framework syntax

Comment: I am using Yii2 Framework @RaoDYC i will try your suggestion.

Comment: `->where(['udated_at = CURDATE()'])`

Comment: Still doesn't work :( I am out of ideas

Comment: How is your table `orders` defined? What is the datatype for the column `updated_at` ?

Comment: In the `updated_at` column i store the date which an order gets the status completed in Unix Time format like `1644952030`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE updated_at >= unix_timestamp('2022-02-21 00:00') and ...`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use just day in this case, since time may vary. If your time is stored in the date() format you can do it like this:

```
$todayDate = strtotime(date("d.m.Y"));
$records = (new Query())->select([
        'sum(price) as count',
        'updated_at as day',
])
->from(Orders::tableName())
->orderBy('day desc')
->groupBy('day')
->indexBy('day')
->limit(1)
->where([
     'AND',
     'status' => Orders::STATUS_COMPLETED, 
     'updated_at' => $tadayDate]
)->all();
```

Or, as usual we have `created_at` and `updated_at` fields in the table, `updated_at` may be empty, in this case, reasonable will be to use `created_at` field to query results:

```
$todayDate = strtotime(date("d.m.Y"));
$records = (new Query())->select([
        'sum(price) as count',
        'created_at as day',
])
->from(Orders::tableName())
->orderBy('day desc')
->groupBy('day')
->indexBy('day')
->limit(1)
->where([
      'AND',
      'status' => Orders::STATUS_COMPLETED, 
      'created_at' => $tadayDate]
)->all();
```

Or use `BETWEEN` for the date, like it was mentioned in the comments.

```
updated_at >= '2022-02-21 00:00' AND updated_at <= '2022-02-21 23:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use group by, order by, index by or limit when all you want is to get sum over one day.

```
$sum = Orders::find()
    ->where(new \yii\db\Expression(
        'DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`updated_at`)) = :today',
        [':today' => date('Y-m-d')]
    ))->sum('price');
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$queue =  Orders::find()
        ->select(['SUM(price) as total'])
        ->where(['DATE(created_at)' => $today])
        ->one();
return $queue['total'];
```